# Show that if $E_1 \subseteq E_2$ then $P(E_1|F) \le P(E_2|F)$

Tags: probability

Currently working my way through Samuel Goldberg's introduction to probability. A question asks to prove the following law

> If $E_1 \subseteq E_2$ then $P(E_1|F) \le P(E_2|F)$

I really am not sure where to start with this one. I assume that I want to reduce $P(E_1|F) \le P(E_2|F)$ to $P(E_1) \le P(E_2)$. I have started by changing each side of the inequality to a fraction:

$$\frac{P(E_1\cap F)}{P(F)} \le \frac{P(E_2\cap F)}{P(F)}$$

and then getting rid of the denominator

$ P(E_1\cap F) \le P(E_2\cap F)$

I am not sure where to go from here. I can't assume that each side reduces to multiplication eg.

$ P(E_1\cap F) = P(E_2)  P(F)$

Or can I?

Thanks.

Comment: If $E_1\subseteq E_2$ then $E_1\cap F\subseteq E_2\cap F$.

Comment: Ok then, so putting aside the step of multiplication, my proof was on the right track. The next step would be to conclude that P(E1)<P(E2) and then E1 is a subset of E2?

Comment: probablyme, that was a useful response. I was taking it in. Any chance of reposting your answer? Thanks.

Comment: From previous comment, $P(E_1\cap F)\le P(E_2\cap F)$, then just divide by $P(F)$, which is positive.

Comment: David. Doesn't this assume independence? I think division by P(F) would only be useful if it helped reduce $P(E_1|F)$ to $P(E_1)$. I thought that $P(E_1|F)$ can only reduce to $P(E_1) * P(F)$ if $P(E_1)$ and $P(F)$ are independent of one another. Can we assume that here? why?

Comment: It looks to me as if you are attacking the problem the wrong way round.  You do not have to prove $P(E_1)\le P(E_2)$, that is given (more or less).

Answer (score 4):

Since $E_{1}\subseteq E_{2}$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
E_{2}=E_{1}\cup(E_{2}\setminus E_{1}),
\end{eqnarray}
where the union is a disjoint union. Thus, we have the following by the (finite) additivity of probability measure:

\begin{align}
P(E_{2}|F)&=P(E_{1}|F)+P((E_{2}\setminus E_{1})|F)\\&\geq P(E_{1}|F),
\end{align}
where the last inequality follows since $P((E_{2}\setminus E_{1})|F) \geq 0$ is true for any probability measure.

Comment: +1 :). In the last sentence, it is better if "from the fact" is replaced by something like "probability (measure) by definition only gives nonnegative reals."; for otherwise the OP may not know whether the "fact" is by derivation or by definition.

Comment: @GudsonChou Thank you for pointing this. I shall edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $A,B$ are measurable sets with $A\subseteq B$ then $\Pr(A)\leq\Pr(B)$.

This because $B=A\cup(B-A)$ with $A$ and $B-A$ disjoint leads to: $$\Pr(A)\leq\Pr(A)+\Pr(B-A)=\Pr(B)$$

Apply this on $A:=E_1\cap F$ and $B:=E_2\cap F$.